# For $m,n\in\Bbb N$, ${\rm Aut}(\Bbb{Z}_n^m)$ is isomorphic to ${\rm GL}_m(\Bbb{Z}_n)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, automorphism-group

I am trying to prove that, for positive integers $m$ and $n$:

\begin{equation*}
\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_n^m) \cong \text{GL}_m(\mathbb{Z}_n)
\end{equation*}

My attempt is to define function $\phi: \text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_n^m)\to \text{GL}_m(\mathbb{Z}_n)$ by letting $\phi(f)$ be the matrix with the $i$th column being $f(0, \cdots, 0,1,0,\cdots,0)$, where the $1$ is at the $i$th position. I was able to prove this map is a well defined injective homomorphism. However, I cannot prove this map is surjective. Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Please do not use mathematics-only titles.

Comment: Hint: you can multiply an $m$-vector by an $m \times m$ matrix.

Comment: Care to elaborate? I still cannot see why it helps the map to be surjective.

Comment: Given $M\in \operatorname{GL}_m(\Bbb Z_n)$, let $f_M\in\operatorname{Aut}(\Bbb Z_n^m$ be the map $x\mapsto Mx$. All you need to do is verify/notice that $f_M$ is actually in $\operatorname{Aut}(\Bbb Z_n^m)$.